# public methods of class not visible in TypeScript/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I have a typescript class as below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouteParamsService {
  public router : ActivatedRoute;

  constructor(){};

  public getRouteParams(){
      return this.router;
  }

}
```

I am using it in my component as below:

```
import { ListItem } from "../../../shared/models/listItem.model";
    import { RouteParamsService } from '../../../shared/services/routeParams.service';

    export class CheckGroupsFilterValues {
        private route = new RouteParamsService();
        public rgr: string[] = []; //responsibilityGroups
        public sys: string[] = []; //systems
        public app: string[] = []; //applications
        public cgr: string[] = []; //checkGroups
        public cgi: string[] = []; //checkGroupInstances
        public nat: string; //needsAttentions

        constructor(){
            this.rgr = ["MULTI_MULTI_Vale_Sellout (4213)"];
            this.sys = ["MULTI_MULTI_Vale_Sellout (4213)"];
            this.app = ["MULTI_MULTI_Vale_Sellout (4213)"];
            this.cgr = ["MULTI_MULTI_Vale_Sellout (4213)"];
            this.cgi = ["MULTI_MULTI_Vale_Sellout (4213)"];

            console.log(this.route);
        }

    }
```

The problem is: `console.log(this.route)` gives the following output, `RouteParamsService {}`.
The public method `getRouteParams()` defined in the class is not visible at all even though I have created an instance already.

Comment: Inject your service in contructor: constructor(private route:RouteParamsService){} and not declare as variable

Comment: The moment I do that `constructor(route : RouteParamsService)`, the following peice of code breaks where component has been used.

filtersValues: new CheckGroupsFilterValues()

Typescript says 1 argument is required, and passed none.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that CheckGroupsFilterValues was a component.

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one wrong things here.

1- The `router` of `RouteParamsService` will always be `undefined` as it is not being assigned anywhere. In needs to be in `constructor` in onder to be injected properly.

```
constructor(public router : ActivatedRoute){};
```

2- `private route = new RouteParamsService();` does not create an Angular service. In order to inject `ActivatedRoute` in the constructor of service, either it needs to be an Angular service (injectable) or you have to manually do it. So, if you create the service with `new`, you have to pass `ActivatedRoute` to service manually.

You can use `Injector` (https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) to manually inject injectables in your custom classes.

**UPDATE**

In order to inject an Angular injectable to a custom class, you can use `Injector`.

First, export an instance of `Injector` from a feature module (in order to avoid circular dependencies) and import the feature module in your app module

```
export let InjectorInstance: Injector;

@NgModule(
 /* *** */
)
export class MyFeatureModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    InjectorInstance = this.injector;
  }
}

-----

@NgModule(
     imports: [
       ...,
       MyFeatureModule,
       ...
     ]
)
export class AppModule {}
```

Then in your custom class, import `InjectorInstance` from the feature module and use it to get injectable reference:

```
import {InjectorInstance} from 'path/to/my-feature-module.module';

export class CheckGroupsFilterValues {
   private route = InjectorInstance.get<RouteParamsService>(RouteParamsService);
};
```

And don't forget to provide your service in `root`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RouteParamsService {...}
```

Comment: The moment I do that `constructor(route : RouteParamsService)`, the following peice of code breaks where component has been used.

filtersValues: new CheckGroupsFilterValues()

Typescript says 1 argument is required, and passed none.

Comment: I edited my answer by telling how to inject an Angular injectable within a custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the router through constructor

```
constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute, // <-- Usefull
    private _router: Router,
  ){}
```

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: The moment I do that `constructor(route : RouteParamsService)`, the following peice of code breaks where component has been used.

filtersValues: new CheckGroupsFilterValues()

Typescript says 1 argument is required, and passed none.

Comment: what are you trying to do with CheckGroupsFilterValues ? @rach8garg